# When i try to destroy the activity so no traces will be stay my program just quit when running it why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For testing purposes, I want my app to avoid leaving any traces when i close it on my android device. When I run the application again, It should start from scratch with all settings/vars everything is cleared/reset to initial settings.

So i'm trying to use the noHistory flag.
This is my top of my MainActivity with the onCreate:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    TextToSpeech mTts;
    private String targetURL;
    private String urlParameters;
    private Button btnClick;
    private String clicking = "clicked";
    private String[] ipaddresses = new String[]{
        "http://192.168.1.5:8098/?cmd=nothing"};
    private String iptouse = "";
    private TextView text;
    private boolean connectedtoipsuccess = false;
    private int counter = 0;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private TextView text1, text2, text3;
    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;
    private TextView timerValue;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private Handler customHandler;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    private int servercheckCounter = 0;
    private byte[] checkServer = null;
    private boolean connectedSuccess = false;
    private TextView status, status1;
    private TextView uploadedfilescount;
    private int numberofuploadedfilescounter = 0;

    String a = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        serverChecksThread.start();
        status1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
        uploadedfilescount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberofuploadedFiles);
        uploadedfilescount.setText("Uploaded Files: 0")
        addListenerOnButton();
        initTTS();
    }
```

And this is the content of the file AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.webservertest" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What i tried to do is to add this line:

android:noHistory="true" i added it here:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true">
```

Then i'm running the program once from the android-studio and then on my android device lg g3 i press the O button. Then when i run the application again this time from the device it self the application show for millisecond and close.

Then i need like more 2-3 times to run it untill it's running and then in some cases it remember some last actions. For example i hear it say something in my MainActivity onCreate:

```
initTTS();
```

I use it to use text to speech:

```
public void initTTS() {
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    }
```

Or if in my application i add text to TextView then sometimes i see the last text change.

On my MainActivity now i have Override of onStop and onStart but they are empty for now i didn't add any code yet.

What i want to do in this case now is when click on my device O and close the app when i run it again from the device that it will be reseted all vars methods activity/ies reseted.

Comment: 1)Hitting the 'O button' as you call it does not close an app. It just makes the phone move to the home screen. 2) If the app is closing when you try to open it again look at logcat. 3) if you override on* it's recommended that you call the super.on* method.

Comment: Just wondering... wouldn't turn on "Don't keep activities" on the Developer Menu do the trick for you? That way activities will be killed everytime they are stopped and you can do your tests.

Answer (score 0):

the O button is handled through  `@OnPause` and `@OnResume` methods ,
put your code to handle the pausing of your application in them , 

but be careful **this is NOT how android application flow is meant to be** .

 the pause is NOT the same as leaving the application .